# Where exactly does the performance advantage of LazyEvaluation emerge from?

Tags: javascript, haskell, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

In the past few days, I have researched LazyEvaluation, in performance aspect mostly, wondering **from where the performance advantage of LazyEvalutaion emerges**.

It's been so unclear to me reading various articles but a very few including

**[What are the advantages of Lazy Evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151226/what-are-the-advantages-of-lazy-evaluation)**

> This refers to **the evaluation of a syntax tree**. If you evaluate a
>   syntax tree lazily (i.e. when the value it represents is needed), you
>   must carry it through the preceeding steps of your computation in its
>   entirety. This is the overhead of lazy evaluation. However, there are
>   two advantages. 1) **you will not evaulate the tree unnecessarily if the
>   result is never used**,

JavaScript, for instance, implemented **if** syntax.

```
if(true)
{
    //to evaluate
}
else
{
    //not to evaluate
}
```

In this ordinary scenario, we don't have any performance issue.

To be evaluated is done, not to be evaluated is ignored in the syntax tree.

However, in some recursive loop, for instance, [Tak function AKA Tarai function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tak_%28function%29)

> function tak(x,y,z){
>       return (x <= y) ? y : 
>           tak(tak(x-1, y, z),
>                       tak(y-1, z, x),
>                       tak(z-1, x, y)); }

Since Eager Evaluation strategy of JS evaluates function(arguments) inevitability, 
the **if - else - not to be evaluated** control no longer works, and the number of evaluation step of **tak function** explodes.

Against to this disadvantage of Eager Evaluation(of JS or other languages), Haskell can evaluate the **tak** without problems as it is, and some JS library such as [lazy.js](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/) outperforms in a specific area like functional programming where recursive list management required.

Aside from infinite list, I understand this is the exact reason for performance advantage of LazyEvaluation. Am I correct?

Comment: For haskell programmers performance is actually one of the tricky parts of lazy evaluation. The real benefits are in expressiveness, allowing the programmer to devise a solution in a number of different ways (e.g. I want to express this bit of code as an infinite list) and  to be able to split solutions into parts that can be composed easily, and flexibly; in a strict language evaluation concerns will dictate how you structure your code. Also you need laziness in order to really have a language that's "declarative", and (ideally) once you have that you don't ever think about "evaluation".

Comment: @jberryman ,thanks for your input. I agree. For the last part, "declarative", aside from lazy, I think we really need to combine the language with IO via event stream in FRP manner. I like your photos in your website by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've got the right idea.

I don't think you need all the complexity though.  Imagine that the JavaScript was

```
if (veryExpensiveFunction()) {
  doThis();
} else {
  doThat();
}
```

Now imagine that `veryExpensiveFunction` is implemented.

```
function veryExpensiveFunction() {
   return true || evenMoreExpensiveFunction();
}
```

If JavaScript because `||` is lazy (only evaluates the second argument if needed) this will return very quickly (because `true` is, well, true!).  If it was implemented instead like

```
function veryExpensiveFunction() {
  var a = true;
  var b = evenMoreExpensiveFunction(); // forces the evaluation

  return a || b;
}
```

This would take ages to evaluate because you've unnecessarily evaluated the arguments.  Now imagine that the magic applied to `||` was applied to every function (i.e. a lazy language) and you can probably imagine the sort of performance advantages that laziness might bring.

In your example

```
function tak(x,y,z){ return (x <= y) ? y : tak(tak(x-1, y, z), tak(y-1, z, x), tak(z-1, x, y)); }
```

Let's imagine that everything was lazy.

```
 var a = tak(1,2,3);
```

This doesn't do anything (nothing needs to be evaluated). `a` isn't used, so nothing is evaluated.

```
 var a = tak(1,2,3);
 console.log(a);
```

Now we're in a position to drive the evaluation of `tak`.  Evaluating as we need to get the results, we first substitute the values in (replace variables with their arguments).  We then evaluate the condition, and then only the side of the conditional that we need.

```
 console.log((1 <= 2) ? 2 : tak(tak(1-1, 2, 3), tak(2-1, 1, 3), tak(3-1, 1, 2));
 console.log(   true  ? 2 : tak(tak(1-1, 2, 3), tak(2-1, 1, 3), tak(3-1, 1, 2));
 console.log(2);
```

In this example (assuming I've not made any horrible typos), then we don't need to evaluate anything else other than the arguments and no recursive calls are made.

Comment: Thank you @Jeff Foster. I haven't noticed || is lazy so far, so very informative. However, this technique can't be applied to recursive functions since we've got pass (args) to call the function and it's evaluated there instantly, correct?

Comment: No.  It's only evaluated as needed.  Someone would have to ask for the result of the recursive function in order to drive the evaluation.

Comment: hmm, It's still not so clear to me. Is it possible to write down a code for the tak function using the lazy || technique, if you don't mind.

Comment: tak(15,5,0) as it is takes 30-60 seconds in my environment. Lazy evaluation language such as Haskell or modified with lazy eval technique shall be instant.

Comment: I'd encourage you to work through an example on pen + paper and only evaluate things when you actually need them.  Doing this "call-by-need" strategy, you'll see that you often don't need to evaluate calls to `tak` because they aren't used.

Comment: Well, thanks you for the dedicated information, @Jeff Foster . I will study. I'd like to hear more feedbacks on this topic, so I dare to remain this question unanswered now.