# regex the first 2 \n within a \n asequence

Tags: javascript, regex

For instance, I have a sourceString
:
`1234\n\n\n\n5678`

and, I want to replace **the first 2 `\n` within a `\n` sequence that must be equal to or more than 2** characters

so, the result I expect goes
:
`1234TEST\n\n5678`

I tried
:
`(^|[^\n])\n{2}`

and  the actual result is: `123TEST\n\n5678`

http://regex101.com/r/cS6uG3

What's wrong with my code?

The basic idea is from @Tim Pietzcker 's tutorial on my previous question.

Thanks.

[Regex to match single new line. Regex to match double new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011260/regex-to-match-single-new-line-regex-to-match-double-new-line)

Comment: So you want to replace the first two `\n` characters even if there are only two?  E.g., `1234\n\n5678` becomes `1234TEST5678`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here is that:

```
(^|[^\n])\n{2}
^-------^ -- this part
```

matches `4` and it's replaced. You need to included it again in your replacement.

```
var string = "1234\n\n\n\n5678";
string.replace(/(^|[^\n])\n{2}/g, "$1TEST");
                                   ^^-- back-reference
```

Comment: Thanks, Frits. Your answer is really clear. Along with my previous post, I understand.

Answer (score 1):

This positive lookahead based regex should work:

```
var repl = "1234\n\n\n\n5678".replace(/\n{2}(?=\n{2,})/, "TEST");
```

`/\n(?=\n{2,})/` means match `\n\n` if it is immediately followed by 2 or more `\n`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I get `1234TEST\n\n\n5678` when I test it (one `\n` too many).

Comment: Sorry misread the requirement earlier, made a correction, check it now.