# Advantage of lazy evaluation of streams in java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have read that the streams are evaluated lazily in the pipeline. It is not executed unless the terminal opertion is invoked on the expression. But, what are the benefits of this lazy evaluation of the expressions? Can someone please explain with some examples

Comment: _pipeline_, _terminal operation_ - you are referring to `Stream`?

Comment: [What are the advantages of lazy evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151226/what-are-the-advantages-of-lazy-evaluation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lazy processing allows for several useful improvements at, essentially, zero cost:

### Simplify multiple operations on a stream

For simplicity, consider some finite stream like a list with `n` element being streamed. Now consider something like:

```
Stream<SomeThing> resultStream = someList.stream();
if (condition1){
    resultStream = resultStream.filter(predicate1);
}

if (condition2){
    resultStream = resultStream.filter(predicate2);
}

if (condition3){
    resultStream = resultStream.filter(predicate3);
}

List<SomeThing> result = resultStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Since the filters are lazily applied this will result in a *single iteration through the `n` elements in the list*. This is exactly an `O(n)` operation. However, filtering the same list eagerly three times will apply three `O(n)` operations on the list. This is more processing than the lazy evaluation does.

### Prepare the stream, execute when needed

Since the source of the stream does not need to be static data (like a list), it can be a dynamic source like an event emitter, reading data over a socket or anything else, then the stream can be prepared in advanced and consumed when needed.

For example, consider an application that attaches to a socket but does not need the data coming in right away. Perhaps only when some condition is met (5 minutes have passed, or some signal is received, or an error occurs, etc.) then the information is to be pulled from the socket. The application will just need to execute a terminal operation only at that point. Until then there are no CPU cycles or network bandwidth consumed for the stream.

### Handling infinite data sources

Eager evaluation of a stream *cannot* handle infinite data sources. This would require infinite memory and processing time which, by definition, is not there. More practically, one has to be extremely careful in setting up expectations before hand.

That is where lazy evaluation can be indispensable, as it handles both finite and infinite data sources in the same idiomatic way. With zero cost. One can even change a stream's source from finite to infinite with little to no changes needed. Changing an eager operation to lazy is non-trivial otherwise.

Comment: Is there a way to verify if the iteration above will happen only once in O(n) time?

Comment: @Abhilash that's the nature of lazy evaluation of stream operators. If you have an infinite data source and the operations are not collected and applied at once, then `stream.filter(predicate1).filter(predicate2).take(1)` would take an infinite time and memory (or until the program crashes) because `.filter(predicate1)` would attempt to walk the entire stream before the `.filter(predicate2)` is run.

Comment: With lazy evaluation, each item is taken and both filters applied to it before moving to the next item. The `.take(1)` would also be an upper bound of returned elements and after an element fulfils both predicates, it's returned and the stream would stop being consumed.

Answer (score 2):

Lazy evaluation of *stream pipelines* in Java has nothing to do with lambdas.

All but the last stations in a *stream pipeline* are evaluated only when the last station asks for more data. When the last station pulls the one second from the last, that one pulls from the one before it and so forth until finally the reqeust for the new data makes all the way to supplier. The supplier then provides next one value which gets propagated back (actually forth) through the pipeline to the last stage (a collector or a forEach) and the cycle repeats.

This approach does not require the pipeline implementation to over-produce and/or buffer anything. This is great for CPU and memory footprint, which is usually a great bias for Java applications.

Example:

```
Stream
    .generate(new Random(42)::nextLong) // <-- supplies the next random number every time the next station pulls it
    .limit(5) // <-- pulls from the generator when is pulled itself
              //     terminates the pipeline after 5 pulls
    .collect(toList()); // <-- pulls data from the pipeline into the list
```